# How to override default CURL timeout for Codeception - using Browserstack

Tags: curl, codeception, browserstack

I am testing Browserstack for acceptance tests. They have a peculiar habit of taking a very long time to respond to certain requests. I am running Codeception and I am always getting the CURL 30 second timeout error. I want to be able to override this timeout but I cannot figure out how to do it. Is this even possible in Codeception?

This is the yml for my acceptance tests:

```
class_name: RemoteAcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: '{my url}'
      curl:
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 120
      host: 'hub.browserstack.com'
      port: 80
      browser: firefox
      capabilities:
        'browserstack.user': '{user}'
        'browserstack.key' : '{key}'
        'browserVersion': '21.0'
        'browserstack.debug': 'false'
        'browserstack.local': 'true' # force use of local BrowserStackLocal binary
```

Is there any setting or any hack I can try to up the timeout to what I want, which is 120 seconds? I know that's a ridiculous amount of time, but Browserstack is a bit 'peculiar' when you are running their local binary.

Comment: With PhpBrowser it should work. I use it to force HTTP1.0 instead of HTTP1.1.http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser

Answer (score -1):

A new release for Codeception is online

[WebDriver] Added WebDriver init settings connection_timeout and request_timeout by @n8whnp #2065

see => http://codeception.com/changelog

Also see the documentation Page

connection_timeout - timeout for opening a connection to remote selenium server (30 seconds by default).
request_timeout - timeout for a request to return something from remote selenium server (30 seconds by default).

here => http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver